# How do you find the state space representation of $G(s) = \frac {1}{s^2+s+1}$

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

Let $G(s) = \frac {1}{s^2+s+1}$ be the transfer function of the system

Then $Y(s)(s^2+s+1) = U(s)$

Therefore $y'' + y' + y = u$

After this step, how should I set up my state transition variable $x$ to characterize this system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define $x_1 = y$ and $x_2 = y'$ so that
\begin{equation}
x_1' = y' = x_2
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
x_2' = y'' = -y' - y + u = -x_2 - x_1 + u. 
\end{equation}

Now set
\begin{equation}
x = \left(\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
x' = \left(\begin{array}{c} x_1' \\ x_2' \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{rr} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{array}\right)x + \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right)u,
\end{equation}
which is in state-space form.

**Edit:** As dustin noted in the comments below, the output equation here would be
\begin{equation}
y = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)x.
\end{equation}

Comment: You are missing a $y$ equation. $$y=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{0}\cdot u$$

Comment: My bad. I just saw state space and only one equation.

Comment: I see, so a second order system need two state variables to be characterized. Makes sense. Voltage 1, voltage 2.

Comment: In making the state definitions, I've always found it helpful to draw out the block diagram with integrators.